# How to set a property in java code using build.xml

Tags: java, ant

I am new to Ant and any help will be appreciated.

What I want to do is:

When I am invoking an Ant target, I am doing :

`ant -DSIMV3.1=true run-tenantManagement`

Now Inside build.xml, I have:

```
<target name="run-tenantManagement" depends="jar">
   <property name="SIMV3.1" value="${SIMV3.1}" />
    ...
</target>
```

Now I want the value of the property SIMV3.1 to be visible inside my java code.
Because in my java code, I want to set a condition that:

```
if(SIMV3.1==true){
//do something
}else{
//do something else
}
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Do you want the variable to be available at compilation time or at runtime? That is, does `run-tenantManagement` use `<java>` or `<javac>`?

Answer (score 3):

Another approach that's more persistent as far as the property value in your target build (i.e. the resulting jar file) is to have ant write the property value to a resource file that gets included in the target jar file.  This gives the property value that gets set during the build a better lifespan (for lack of a better word) so that it can be made available in the project's (i.e. build's) products. For instance, an example ant file may look like:

```
<project name="sandbox" basedir="." default="build">
    <condition property="SIMV3.1" value="${SIMV3.1}" else="false">
        <isset property="SIMV3.1"/>
    </condition>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete verbose="${verbose}" dir="bin" failonerror="false"/>
        <delete verbose="${verbose}" file="lib/sandbox.jar" failonerror="false"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin"/>
    </target>

    <target name="resources">
        <echo file="bin/sandbox/resources/SIMV3.1">${SIMV3.1}</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="compile, resources">
        <mkdir dir="lib"/>
        <jar destfile="lib/sandbox.jar" basedir="bin">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="sandbox.Sandbox"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
   </target>
</project>
```

The **condition** task defaults the property value to false if it's not provided and the *resources* tasks writes the property value to the resource file that will be included in the jar file (in the *build* task).  Therefore building like this:

```
ant -DSIMV3.1=true
```

will result in a "true" value being written to the **SIMV3.1** file in the *resources* package.  Invoking ant without specifying the property will result in a default property of *false* being written to that resource file.

In the code this resource can be accessed via **InputStream** by reading the first (and only) line from the file and parsing that line using the **Boolean** class like so:

```
package sandbox;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String resource = "/sandbox/resources/SIMV3.1";
        InputStream stream = Sandbox.class.getResourceAsStream(resource);
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
        boolean simv3_1 = false;

        try {

            simv3_1 = Boolean.parseBoolean(buffer.readLine());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("SIMV3.1 = " + simv3_1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of sysproperty in java ant task to set the property.

```
<target name="run-tenantManagement" depends="jar">
    <java classname="props"    fork="true">
        <sysproperty key="SIMV3.1"
             value="${SIMV3.1}"
             />
    </java>
</target>
```

This can be read in java class as below,

```
import java.util.Properties;
public class props {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String     testProp = "SIMV3.1";
        Properties sysProps = System.getProperties();
        System.out.println( "Value of " + testProp + " is " +
                        sysProps.getProperty(testProp) );
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is it necessary that we print its value in main() ?
If I print it it some constructor/other method, its coming out to be null

Comment: Nope, I used main only as an example. Are you sure you are accessing the property in the same java class as mentioned in classname attribute in java task (  <java classname= **"props"**  ..) ?

Comment: I missed this exception.I am getting
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/oracle/common/Constants
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.oracle.common.Constants

Comment: That is self explanatory, you have missed to include classpath to find Constants class. You can create classpath and refer it in the java task.
 
PS: This exception is not relevant to this thread. Please stick to the issue the thread is meant for. You can ask separate question if you are stuck and need help

Comment: I have resolved the classpath issue but now I am getting
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

So, why is it looking for main method?

Comment: My bad, have a look at [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) . This task needs a executable class or if you are running a jar, jar should have the main class entry in the manifest.