# How to access build.xml property in testng class

Tags: java, xml, ant, build, testng

I am trying to access `build.xml` properties in my testng test. I have two properties in my xml, I am able to access one of them in my Java/testng code. The other one coming as null. My build.xml looks like this:

```
<target name="beta">
  <property name="TestRunConfig" value="-DTestRunConfig=${bp:pkg.src}/src/path/configuration/Beta.configuration"/        
  <property name="domain" value="-Ddomain=beta"/>
  <antcall target="testrun">        
  </antcall>
</target>
```

This is my java code:

`System.out.println("TestRunConfig = " + System.getProperty("TestRunConfig"));`
`System.out.println("domain = " + System.getProperty("domain"));`

This is the output:

`[testng] TestRunConfig = /Users/goyaly/alexamayday_workspace/src/path/configuration/Beta.configuration
   [testng] domain = null`

Why is the `domain` coming up as `null` while the other property `TestRunConfig` is printed correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700193/how-to-set-a-property-in-java-code-using-build-xml

Comment: I have tried this already. This doesn't work. My class is a testng class, can this be why its not working?

Comment: I got this resolved. The issue was, I was missing `<jvmarg value="${domain}"/>` in my testrun target. That's why it was not picking it up. Thanks